# how to create private key with passphrase in openssl

Tags: openssl, private-key, csr, passphrase, non-interactive

I am creating **private key** and **csr** as follows:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./private.key -out ./mycsr.csr -subj "CN=blah"
```

I understand since the above command has a **-nodes**(no des) , the private key will not be having a passphrase.

I want to generate **private key with passphrase** and create a csr out of this key. How do I do that in **non-interactive** way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: If ***`blah`*** is a server name or IP address, then ***`"CN=blah"`*** is just plain wrong nowadays.... Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21297139) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812) Both discuss what names should go where.